# I would like to know how to rotate around Z-axis of a mesh created with THREE.JS using the mouse

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, mesh, z-axis

I'm implementing the function to rotate the mesh using the mouse.

referencing code is linked site.
("http://3dit.bordeaux.inria.fr/testbed.html#navigation_Map_Navigation")

I would like to know how to use the mouse to rotate around the Z axis (red line).

I have found that all of the examples in Three.js have only a way to rotate around the x or y axis.

Really need help.

---

### My code : https://jsfiddle.net/pfk7j7a3/3/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CustomOrbit = function () {
        var EPS = 0.000001;
        var rotateStart = new THREE.Vector2();
        var rotateEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
        var rotateDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

        var phiDelta = 0;
        var thetaDelta = 0;

        var target = new THREE.Vector3();

        /// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
        var minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
        var maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.91;

        var onMouseDownPosition = new THREE.Vector2();

        this.Initialize = function () {
            renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
        }

        var onMouseMove = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            rotateEnd.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);
            rotateDelta.subVectors(rotateEnd, rotateStart);

            thetaDelta -= 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / renderer.domElement.clientWidth;
            phiDelta -= 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / renderer.domElement.clientHeight;

            var position = camera.position;
            var offset = position.clone().sub(target);

            // angle from z-axis around y-axis          
            var theta = Math.atan2(offset.x, offset.z);
            theta += thetaDelta;

            // angle from y-axis
            var phi = Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z), offset.y);
            phi += phiDelta;
            phi = Math.max(minPolarAngle, Math.min(maxPolarAngle, phi));// restrict phi to be between desired limits
            phi = Math.max(EPS, Math.min(Math.PI - EPS, phi));          // restrict phi to be between EPS and PI-EPS

            var radius = offset.length();
            radius = Math.max(0, Math.min(Infinity, radius)); // restrict radius to be between desired limits

            offset.x = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
            offset.y = radius * Math.cos(phi);
            offset.z = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);

            position.copy(target).add(offset);

            camera.lookAt(target);

            thetaDelta = 0;
            phiDelta = 0;

            rotateStart.copy(rotateEnd);
        }
        var onMouseUp = function (event) {
            renderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
            renderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
        }

        var onMouseDown = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, camera.near);
            vector.unproject(camera);
            raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize(), camera.near, camera.far);
            intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(pickingMesh);

            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                target = intersects[0].point;
                rotateStart.set(event.clientX, event.clientY);

                renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
                renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var camera, scene, renderer, pickingMesh, rendWidth = 500, rendHeight = 500;
    init();
    makeMesh();
    makeAxis(200);
    animate();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: false });
        renderer.setSize(500, 500);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, 500 / 500, 0.1, 10000);
        camera.position.x = 200000;
        camera.position.y = 400000;
        camera.position.z = 300;
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(200000, 400000, 0.0));
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }


    //create red square mesh
    function makeMesh() {
        var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        var vertices = new Float32Array([
            200000 - 100.0, 400000 - 100.0, 0.0,
            200000 + 100.0, 400000 + 100.0, 0.0,
            200000 - 100.0, 400000 + 100.0, 0.0,

            200000 - 100.0, 400000 - 100.0, 0.0,
            200000 + 100.0, 400000 - 100.0, 0.0,
            200000 + 100.0, 400000 + 100.0, 0.0
        ]);

        geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        pickingMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        scene.add(pickingMesh);
    }

    function makeAxis(axisLength) {
        var x_axis = new THREE.Geometry(); x_axis.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(200000 - axisLength, 400000, 0), new THREE.Vector3(200000 + axisLength, 400000, 0));
        var y_axis = new THREE.Geometry(); y_axis.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(200000, 400000 - axisLength, 0), new THREE.Vector3(200000, 400000 + axisLength, 0));
        var z_axis = new THREE.Geometry(); z_axis.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(200000, 400000, -axisLength), new THREE.Vector3(200000, 400000, axisLength));
        var x_axis_line = new THREE.Line(x_axis, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ linewidth: 1, transparent: true, color: 0x0000ff }));
        var y_axis_line = new THREE.Line(y_axis, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ linewidth: 1, transparent: true, color: 0x00ff00 }));
        var z_axis_line = new THREE.Line(z_axis, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ linewidth: 1, transparent: true, color: 0xff0000 }));
        scene.add(x_axis_line);
        scene.add(y_axis_line);
        scene.add(z_axis_line);
    };

    var myOrbit = new CustomOrbit();
    myOrbit.Initialize();
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure, you want to rotate object, not a camera?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to rotate out of 0,0,0 position (camera around something, object on some position around center), mathematics will start to be more complicated.

My best experience is with orbit controls.
https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

You can set a angle limitation and pan limitation.